# Number of rows inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I wanted to find number of rows used inside a div. I used below code but it is not working.

## Jquery Code

```
$(function() {
   var addDiv = $('#bkup_docs');
   var i = $('#bkup_docs tr').length + 1;
   alert(i); 
});
```

## HTML

```
<div id="bkup_docs">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td align="right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Here I am getting output as 1,actually it should be two.

Am I missing something or I cannot do like this?

Comment: what a html structure is this..? It is invalid..!

Comment: `Div`s can't contain `tr` directly you need to use `table`!

Comment: Works [as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/udQs6/) with the correct markup.

Answer (score 1):

first you were missing table tag.
your html

```
<div id="bkup_docs">
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td align="right"></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

then your jquery

```
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#bkup_docs');
var i = $('#bkup_docs table tr').length;
alert(i); 
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/WKjGL/1/)

Comment: @downvoter: can you explain me what's wrong in this code? please

Comment: My markup is actually like below.

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
 <td align="right">Account # </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="acct_nmbr" id="acct_nmbr" required maxlength="19"/></td>
    </tr>

    <div id="bkup_docs">    
    <tr>
    <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>   
    </div>
    <tr>
 <td align="right">Amount # </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="amnt" id="amnt" required maxlength="19"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

Comment: My intention is I need to add row dynamically inside this div(id="bkup_docs") only while clicking on a link and also need to remove those rows while clicking on another link.

Comment: first of all you can nest div inside table without tr. check out fiddle for your formatted markup.
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/sm9mn/1/

Comment: I had done like this. But if I am adding a table inside this div then my entire design will get break. At this time I dont wanna work on the design again.Could you please help me to find a way to add rows dynamically inside this div, I am in little trouble to find a solution for this.Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/NVXjv/. Here my design is breaking in such a way that dynamically added rows are getting added up in the top. This design breaking issue will be better noticable as my form is big.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't have tr tags outside a table tag. They are automatically removed. It returns 1 because 0 ($('#bkup_docs tr').length) + 1 = 1. Replace "div" with "table" and it should work.

Comment: @downvoter could you explain why? This answer was totally correct to the original question (someone edited it and added the missing table-tag afterwards as you can see if you view the versions).

Answer (score 0):

1.)Your Html code is valid.

2.)don't add +1 in jquery code.

3.)check working code below

```
<script>

$(function() {

   var i = $('#bkup_docs tr').length;
   alert(i); 
});

</script>
```